# Looping in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Basically I want to select data from a table based on id's of another table. So the algorithm goes:

```
foreach i in (select distinct id from table1)
{
  select * from table2 where table2.id=i;
}
```

How to perform this function with an SQL query? I understand that we could use joins etc instead of looping, however, my requirement is such that I need to pass id's one by one in a for-loop only.

Comment: Use a JOIN to data from both tables, or a sub-query to get only data from one.

Comment: My requirement is such that I have to pass id's one at a time only. This is because table 2 is having huge amount of data and just using a WHERE clause, gives a temp tablespace error. However, if I query the massive table using specific id's it returns the required value

Comment: Then post the query you are using, the execution plan, the table definitions and the **exact** error message. And you don't need PL/SQL for this. A plain SQL query will do.

Comment: You could either do it programmatically with a specific PL (e.g. C#) or you could use stored procedure in a specific RDMBS (e.g. MSSQL, mySQL). But which one do you wan to go, with a PL or with an RDBMS? Of course you could call also the store proc from your PL of choice.

Comment: I am using SQL Developer, Oracle DB

Comment: If you have an issue "with temp tablepace" (whatever that means) then a PL/SQL loop won't help you with that.

Comment: How big is table1? A join of these tables ought to be a simple hash join, and the smaller set of data, which would be the result of "select distinct id from table1" would be hashed. I can't believe that is so large. Why don't you post the real query and execution plan etc, possibly in another question?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table2 where table2.id IN (select distinct id from table1)
```

Comment: I have tried using IN, EXISTS. These also give temp tablepace issue. If only I could pass id's one at a time, I will be able to get the results

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` instead of `foreach`.

Place PL/SQL into a `begin .... end;` block (but see the `declare` below)

The `=i` should read `=i.id` as `i` is the complete record from the select statement, but you're only interested in its `id` field.

In PL/SQL, a `select` statement must be fetched `into` a variable. Therefore, you have to declare an according variable: `r table1%rowtype`

The declaration of such variables is in the `declare ...` section of PL/SQL blocks.

The "algorithm" then becomes

```
declare
  r table2%rowtype;
begin
  for i in (select distinct id from table1) loop
     select * into r from table2 where table2.id = i.id;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using the above query but am unable to declare table2. I am accessing it via a DBLink. So I have written query like this:

    declare
      table2 user.table_name@dbLink;
      r table2%rowtype;
    begin
      for i in (select distinct id from table1) loop
         select * into r from table2 where table2.id = i.id;
      end loop;
    end;

This is giving error

Comment: `declare r table2@dblink%rowtype;`

Comment: But how to use this table2 in the select clause. How to give this an alias?

Comment: On doing this I am getting teh below error:

ORA-06550: line 7, column 35:
PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
ORA-06550: line 7, column 6:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action: